# Google Analytics - Tracking a view with multiple custom dimensions values

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to add more data to my Google Analytics report regarding the use of my Android app.

I started using custom dimensions since yesterday and didn't get any results yet and I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

I want to tie a page view with additional information to be sent with it, and that's why I'm using custom dimensions. In the onCreate method of a specific activity I'm doing this -

```
            Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();

            tracker.setCustomDimension(1, 128));
            tracker.setCustomDimension(2, 2));
            tracker.setCustomDimension(3, 45));
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackView();
```

I've set my custom report to work by the Screen Views metric, and by one of the dimension Id's from above.

Will all of this data be sent along with the trackView command? Because I still can't see any data from yesterday.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. This time I needed to wait about 2 days for the data to appear.

Now I need to figure out how to show the data from all these dimensions at once, but I guess this fits another question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with GA tracking using the android sdk api but I did find [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets) in the GA documentation. In the code examples they use the following as the trigger:

`tracker.sendView();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like its only a minor cosmetic change from trackView. According to this link - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/changelog   - " Changed track methods to send (e.g. trackView now called sendView)." Though I will try to update my analytics version and see if maybe this is the cause